# How to access controller in zend module

Tags: zend-framework, module, routes

My zend application was originally set up like this:

application
  - controller
  - model
  - view

Now I want to set it up to use modules structures, so I changed it like this:
application
  - modules
      - default
          - controller
          - model
          - view
      - test
          - controller
          - model
          - view
Beside moving all the files to the right structure, I just add the following lines to the config file:
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
and add the Bootstrap file for each module.

Since I moved all the current controllers to the default module, I'm able run the application fine.  However, I cannot access any new controller in the new test module.  Am I missing something? Do I have to change anything in config or bootstrap?

For example, I created a new controller in the test module called TestController, and when I go to localhost/test/test, I'm getting error: "EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER".

Answer (score 0):

maybe check your module bootstrap routes

```
    class Transfer_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
    {

    public function _initModuleRoutes()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
        $frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();

        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'modulename/:action/*',
            array(
                    'module' => 'modulename',
                    'controller' => 'modulecontroller',
                    'action' => 'index'
            )
        );
        $router->addRoute('routename', $route);

        return $router;
    }
```

Comment: I added this function to the module bookstrap file, but I'm still getting the same error "Invalid controller specified".  It seems like it does recognize the module, but not the controller.